# Union Two Case Statements SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

```
CASE WHEN msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.sequence_number = '1'
      THEN CONCAT(msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_typical, ' (For 1 Hour  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_temp, '°C  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_speed, ' RPM  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_load, 'N)') 
END AS '4-Ball Wear Test #1',

CASE WHEN msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.sequence_number = '2' 
      THEN CONCAT(msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_typical, ' (For 1 Hour  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_temp, '°C  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_speed, ' RPM  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_load, 'N)') 
END AS '4-Ball Wear Test #2'
```

So thats my code I am getting the following out

```
material_id              4-Ball Wear Test #1               4-Ball Wear Test #2
121               0.5 (1 Hour @ 75°C @ 1200 RPM @ 45 N)         --------
121                          ----------            0.32 (1 Hour @ 25°C @ 1200 RPM @ 2045 N)
```

I would love to merge these rows so that they become one row.  Any ideas?  This is a small portion of a huge SQL Statement that queries a lot of other things.  However the data is identical across each row besides these two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT() function and put case condition query in subquery.

```
SELECT materialID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`4-Ball Wear Test #1`,`4-Ball Wear Test #2`) separator ',')
FROM
(
SELECT materialId,
CASE WHEN msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.sequence_number = '1'
      THEN CONCAT(msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_typical, ' (For 1 Hour  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_temp, '°C  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_speed, ' RPM  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_load, 'N)') 
END AS '4-Ball Wear Test #1',

CASE WHEN msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.sequence_number = '2' 
      THEN CONCAT(msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_typical, ' (For 1 Hour  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_temp, '°C  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_speed, ' RPM  @  ', 
                  msdgen.user_tds_ball_wear.ball_wear_load, 'N)') 
END AS '4-Ball Wear Test #2'

FROM tableName
) as Z
GROUP BY Z.materialID
```

Comment: the thing with this is, I am making a tool to filter out by data values.  So this is just two data properties of 100.  So i generate a SQL query that looks like



SELECT A1, A2, Case1, Case2, Case3, A4 FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.material_id = T2.material_id LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 ON T1.material_id=T3.material_id WHERE (A TON OF USER CONSTRAINTS)


Im thinking a view might be the best bet